# Changing Detail tab property from <h2> to <span>

Tags: magento-1.9, css, rwd-theme

I've spent a few hours now trying to find this here on Magento StackOverflow.
By default in the RWD theme, the Details tab below the short product description is hidden and in an `<h2>` tag.

The hidden part is in the CSS and I don't mind it being hidden, but I do mind it being an `<h2>`. As SEO teaches us, a layout/design item shouldn't be a heading of any kind.

Now I searched my behind off to find the item both in the template files or the css, but I cannot find where it gets `<h2>` appointed and how to change it to `<span>` like all the other tabs in that space.

Product page: https://www.medicinalewietolie.com/cbd-olie-raw-5-naturel-10ml-medihemp.html

Code snippet here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZIOB.jpg

Comment: do you want to change <h2> tag with <span> right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `<h2>` tag is coming from `app/code/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/description.phtml`

The contents of that file have the following in there

```
<?php $_description = $this->getProduct()->getDescription(); ?>
<?php if ($_description): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Details') ?></h2>
    <div class="std">
        <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In order to change that `<h2>` to a `<span>` you'll need to copy that file into `app/code/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view/description.phtml` and change the `<h2>` to a `<span>`

Comment: It is actually without the /code in between but yes, that is it. I couldn't get it found. Thanks !